# Leading '1's instead of leading '0's in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting, f-string

Instead of 007, I wish to print 117, using string formatting.

But instead, it adds 12 empty characters before the 7. Tried using a variable too, in place of the 1. No luck. Please help.

Code:

```
num=7

print(f'{num:03d}')

print(f'{num:13d}')


val=1

print(f'{num:{val}3d}')
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6uMm.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CqJ7.png)

Comment: `.rjust(3, '1')`

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
num=7
print(f'{num:03d}')
print(f'{num:13d}')
print(f'{num:1>3d}')
val=1
print(f'{num:{val}>3d}')
```

output

```
007
            7
117
117
```

To avoid ambiguity, always [specify the alignment option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).